# Github Pages is not loading Bootstrap styling although it's perfectly ok running it locally (with gulp)

Tags: css, gulp, github-pages, gulp-sass, bootstrap-5

I'm still new to web development and can't get this to work.

This is how my project looks currently when I run it locally with gulp:
[image: project run locally]

and here it is how it looks on Github Pages:

https://bolshed.github.io/hrisopack/

I've installed Bootstrap 5 as I want to learn working this way, not the CDN/Quick Start way. The environment (gulp, gulp-sass & browser-sync) is working totally ok with custom styling and all but not on Github Pages.

So looks like it's not loading my Bootstrap styles. I pushed also the Bootstrap folder. Is this necessary?

Here's the current repository: https://github.com/bolshed/hrisopack

How am I supposed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace link to the CSS file with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/styles.css">` it's working that way

Comment: Thank you. Works now. What about that node_modules/bootstrap folder? Do I need it on the repository?

Comment: No, you don't need the `node_modules` on your GitHub repository, you can add it in the `.gitignore` file